# Keep getting an error: listDevices.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Json file with information about various **devices:**

```
    {
  "devices": {
    "deviceList": [
      {
        "name": "iPhone X",
        "id": "193ywpe740",
        "deviceType": "Mobile",
        "os": "iOS",
        "brand": "Apple",
        "quantity": 3,
      },
      {
        "deviceType": "Tablet",
        "name": "Apple iPad (Wi-Fi, 32GB) - Gold",
        "brand": "Apple",
        "os": "MacOS",
        "id": "1563175150",
        "quantity": 5
      },
      {...}
```

**My cardList js file:**

```
import ReservationsListCard from "components/reservationsListCard";

const CardListSection = () => {
  const devices_url =
    "devices.json";

  const [listDevices, setListDevices] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const devicesResponse = await fetch(devices_url);
        const devicesJson = await devicesResponse.json();
        const [listDevices] = devicesJson.devices.deviceList;


        setListDevices(listDevices);
      } catch (error) {
        //console.log("error", error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="device-list-section">
      {listDevices.map((device) => (
        <ReservationsListCard key={device.id} />
      ))}

      {console.log(listDevices)}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardListSection;
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get the "id" of every device and pass it to my *ReservationsListCard* component which then takes that id and displays devices name, brand, image, etc. but I keep running in to the error in the title. What could I be doing wrong ? My theory is that I am not selecting the id's of the devices. Or maybe it's a problem with the component *ReservationsListCard* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the line

`const [listDevices] = devicesJson.devices.deviceList;`

You're trying to destructure (pull out the) first element of device list and assign it to list devices but you really just want to set listDevices to the device list. Try

`const listDevices = devicesJson.devices.deviceList;`

The error occurs because listDevices gets assigned to the first device in the list which is an object and has no `map` function

Comment: Thanks for the correction ! Sadly it still doesn't work. Now I'm getting an error for each of the devices in the Json file. The error in question is:  *TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')*

Comment: @yungbruhM I can't help without knowing more. Is the error now insideReservationListCard or still in CardListSection?

Comment: It's in the *ReservatuibListCard* component 
**The error:** 
  `import "./reservations-list-card.scss";

const ReservationsListCard = ({`
 The error is at this line: `device: { id, name, brand, quantity, image }, 
}) => {
  return (
    <a href={"/device/" + id} className="reservations-list-card">
      <img className="reservations-list-card__image" alt="device" src={image} />`

Comment: Ok so now the problem is you're expecting the device to be passed into ReservationListCard but you aren't passing it in inside CardListSection, you need `<ReservationsListCard key={device.id} device={device} />`

Comment: It worked ! Thank you so much !